# Laravel 9: Converting An Image From Bytes To Jpeg From Storage Directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9 and I wanted to show an image which is stored at **storage/app/avatars**.

So I tried this at the Blade:

```
{{ \App\Http\HelperClasses\ImageHelper::admAvatar() }}
```

And this is the `ImageHelper` Class:

```
namespace App\Http\HelperClasses;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ImageHelper
{
    public static function admAvatar()
    {
        $content = Storage::get('avatars/profile.png');

        return Response::make($content)->header('content-type','image/jpeg');
    }
}
```

So I tried making an image from the `profile.png` and return it after all.

But the problem is it does not show anything!

And when I `dd(Response::make($content)->header('content-type','image/jpeg'))`, I get this:

[image]

And the result of `dd($content)` also goes like this:

[image]

So how can I convert this properly into an image?

Comment: how are you going to "render" the image? in that kind of frontend? You can convert it in a base64 and try to load that in the <img> tag, no?

Comment: I did it like this 
Controller: ```public function getFile($type, $id) { $contents = Storage::get($file_path); return response($contents, 200, $headers); }```

Routes: ```Route::get('/attachments/display/{parent_type}/{parent_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AttachmentController::class, 'display']);```

HTML: ```<img src="/attachments/display/avatar/1" />```

Comment: @justrusty Please add it as answer so it is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this

Controller:

```
public function getFile($type, $id) {
    $attachment = Attachment::where([['parent_type', $type], ['parent_id', $id]])->latest()->firstOrFail();
    $headers = ['content-type' => 'image/jpeg'];
    $contents = Storage::get($attachment->file_path); 
    return response($contents, 200, $headers); 
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/attachments/display/{type}/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AttachmentController::class, 'getFile']);
```

HTML:

```
<img src="/attachments/display/avatar/1" />
```